# Is it possible to make a tablelayoutpanel resizable in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

i have a tablelayoutpanel and also several control inside, see the pic

[image]

the dark grey square is a datagridview, i want the users can resize the tablelayoutpanel by themselves, any one know how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make TableLayoutPanel with resizable cells like using Splitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069443/how-to-make-tablelayoutpanel-with-resizable-cells-like-using-splitter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SplitContainer class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx

https://www.dotnetperls.com/splitcontainer

SplitContainer presents a resizable view. It splits the layout of your Windows Forms window into two parts: a left and right half, or a top and bottom half. It gives the user more control over how the window is arranged.